# using SetString in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, prepared-statement

I'm having a problem using `setString` in for loop.

I have this line to insert into a table in my database

**12.S777.V77.D88.wagon/1.Train/889**

and 777 represent the number of passengers in second class.The problem is that the number of passenger is variable and can take to 3 cases ,like this example:

**12.F123.S777.V77.wagon/1.Train/889**

*code*

```
String rs="insert into ligne1(date,immatr,number_passenger,version,wagon,train) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(rs);

ps.setString(1, message[0]);
ps.setString(2, message[1]);
ps.setString(3, message[2]);

int b=0;

for(b=4;b<chaine.length-1;b++){
    ps.setString(b,melement[b]);
}

//I'm stuck here ! :(

ps.setString(5, message[3]);
ps.setString(6, message[4]);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I don't understand the loop or what is variable. Your SQL statement has six placeholders, so you need to bind exactly six parameters.

Comment: Hm, I don't really understand that. Where exactly is the problem `ps.setString(5, ...)`?

Comment: Your `for` loop does not seem to make sense.

Comment: Next time, please indent your code properly

Comment: so okey my code is a mess i know :$ but how can i insert a String table  into a table in a database

Comment: We can't see how `chaine` and `message` are being populated, but there does seem to be a fundamental issue with how many parameters your are setting - since your SQL statement has 6 question marks, you should only be using `setString` with the values 1 through 6 as the first argument, but the for loop could go higher than 6 delending on `chaine.length-1`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an input format with a variable number of fields. In that case, splitting the string at the `.` is not enough, you'll have to *parse* the data.

I'd implement a simple value holder class for a wagon and some logic to create an instance based on an input string. Like:

```
public class Ligne1 {
   private String date;
   private int seatsInFirstClass;
   private int seatsInSecondClass;
   // ...

   public Ligne1(String data) {
     String values[] = data.split("\.");
     for (String value:values) {
       if (value.startsWith("F")) {
         setSeatsInFirstClass(value);
       } else if (value.startsWith("wagon")) {
         setWagon(value);
       } 
       // ...
     }
   }

   private void setSeatsInFirstClass(String value) {
     seatsInFirstClass = Integer.parseInt(value.substring(1));
   }
   public int getSeatsInFirstClass() {
     return seatsInFirstClass;
   }

   // if we need the total
   public int getNumberOfPassengers() {
     return seatsInFirstClass + seatsInSecondClass;
   }

   // ...
}
```

Finally you use an instance of `Ligne1` and its getter methods to set the values on the prepared statement.

(*Note: the code only gives a hint to the solution I'd choose, it's incomplete and does not handle errors in the source data*)